# Sticky side nav / panel

Tags: html, css

So i just want the side nav to stick to the positioned height and scroll with the user as they travel down the page, but no combination of absolute, relative/ fixed seems to work.

Here is the CSS

```
.side-panel {
  padding: 30px 0;
  position: absolute;
    Z-INDEX: 30;
}
.b > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -110px;
    transform: translate(0) translateZ(0);
    width: 150px;
    transition: transform .3s .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="side-panel b">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#home"><span class="entypo-plus-circled"></span><span class="menu-item">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Environment"><span class="entypo-plus-circled"></span><span class="menu-item">Environment</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Certification"><span class="entypo-mail"></span><span class="menu-item">Certification</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#NAHB"><span class="entypo-doc-text-inv"></span><span class="menu-item">NAHB</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#FAQs"><span class="entypo-layout"></span><span class="menu-item">FAQs</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/bgandy94/xLvtkud2/

I just changed the `.b > ul` tag to position fixed, it scrolls with the page like you mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't work, I've played around with absolutes and statics, so i'm not sure why it seems to not want to move.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding then what you're wanting for the nav to do. In the fiddle I've provided, as a user scrolls down the page, the nav stays exactly as is. Is this not what you're wanting? @moliminous